# foreach error with PHP but $.each working in JS

Tags: php, jquery, foreach

Ok I am having a small issue I am trying to turn this jQuery to PHP

What I need what to do is place this in a foreach function this is what I do first the jQuery code.

```
$.each(obj.products, function(i, obj) {

    if(obj.barcode == barcode)
    {
        $("#showmoreinfohere").show();
        $("#moremovietop").html(obj.name.toUpperCase());
        $("img#selectedproduct").attr('src', ''+obj.logoURL+'');
        $("span#perticket").html(obj.price);
        currentproduct["barcode"] = obj.barcode;
        currentproduct["priceperticket"] = obj.price;
        currentproduct["cashbackperticket"] = obj.discount;
        $("span#VIPCashBack").html(obj.discount);
        total = obj.price * $("#qtyselect").val();
        $("span#totalprice").html("$"+total);
    }
});
```

My PHP CODE

```
<?php
    $cartdata = $fetch->cartitems($_COOKIE["sessionkey"]);
    foreach ($cartdata as $cart)
    {
        $product_details = $fetch->getbarcode('$cart["barcode]"');
    ?>

    <tr>
        <?php 
        foreach ($product_details as $product)
        {
        ?>

        <td><?php $product['name']?></td>
        <td><?php $product['price']?></td>
        <td><?php $cart['qty']?></td>
        <td><?php $product['discount']?></td>
        <?
        }
        ?>

    <?php
    }

 ?>
```

the error I get is

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/movies/public_html/tpl/cart.tpl on line 27

ISSUE from Googling this is what I am finding:

1. you can do a foreach inside a foreach
2. JSON for product_details are returning the following

   ```
     {
      "_id": ObjectId("4f6ab67338fc5ded4f000000"),
      "company": "village",
      "logo": "http: \/\/...\/villagetop.png",
      "products": {
        "0": {
          "barcode": "236690091",
          "name": "Weekday",
          "logoURL": "http: \/\/...\/ticketpic1.png",
          "price": "12.50",
          "discount": "1.50" 
       },
       ...
     },
      "store_name": "movies" 
   }
   ```

Comment: What does the PHP code do? Does it give you any errors? Or does it just not work at all?

Comment: this  won't  display anything as you are not echoing anything

Comment: Which part of the error message is it that you do not understand in specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Before attempting to find answers, it's recommended that you add the following two lines at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

**Edit 2**

From the JSON dump you should use either `$product_details->products` or `$product_details['products']` in your `foreach` loop, depending on how you called `json_decode()`.

---

The following code:

```
$product_details = $fetch->getbarcode('$cart["barcode]"');
```

Not likely to work, the proper code for that it:

```
$product_details = $fetch->getbarcode($cart['barcode']);
```

---

Inside your loop:

```
<td><?php $product['name']?></td>
```

This does not output anything, you want something like this:

```
<td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product['name']); ?></td>
```

Comment: @RussellHarrower you probably either need `$product_details->products` or $product_details['products']` in your foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Since the product details is not coming back as an array, you are receiving the error.  Might could fix it like this:

```
<?php

$cartdata = $fetch->cartitems($_COOKIE["sessionkey"]);
foreach ($cartdata as $cart)
{
    /* This is returning null or invalid data so it is erroring on the loop below....  
       Maybe this function could return array() if empty so it passes the loop in the   
       block below. Otherwise a check is needed before entering the loop.
    */  

    $product_details = $fetch->getbarcode($cart['barcode']);
?>

    <tr>
        <?php             
        // Errors here due to null or invalid data
        foreach ($product_details as $product)
        {
        ?>
            <td><?php echo $product['name']?></td>
            <td><?php $product['price']?></td>
            <td><?php $cart['qty']?></td>
            <td><?php $product['discount']?></td>
      <? } 
}?>
```

Edit:  Saw that you posted the json, but what comes back when you run this?

```
 $product_details = $fetch->getbarcode($cart['barcode']);
 var_dump( $product_details  );
```